# When I click cancel button I want to stop the countdown

Tags: android

When I click the start button the countdown timer works correctly but when I click the cancel button my app get closed.

```
private View.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener= new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  // checking button is clicked
           switch(v.getId()){
               case R.id.b_pick:
                   start();             //start button
                   break;
               case R.id.b_cancel:
                   cancel();              //cancel button
                   break;

           }

            }
    };
```

FOllowing code is the countdown timer method.after clicking cancel button I want to stop the countdowntimer time and set the text of result3 label to "cancel".

```
  private void count() {
            countDownTimer : new CountDownTimer(difference,1000) {      // setting countdown time as date difference in miliseconds
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    result3.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000)+" seconds");

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    result3.setText("finished"); // on finish set text to finished

                }
            }.start();  // starting the countdown timer
        }


    // cancel countdown
        public void cancel(){
            //result2.setText("canceled");
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    if(countDownTimer!=null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        result3.setText("canceled");
        countDownTimer = null;
}
    }
```

Comment: Your are adding this line (countDownTimer.cancel()) to cancel it two times. Remove the one before the if not null. And see your logcat what it says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hint.. I would recommend using one button that will, depending on whether the timer is on or off, control the timer. You can set a global flag (bool) to know whether the timer is on or off. I'm not sure if I got your question right though.